# Static analysis data combined with dynamic analysis knowledge

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, static-analysis, dynamic-analysis, debugging

What I'm doing now is placing an awful lot of comments about function variable values, global variable values as comments in my IDA database, which I find ugly after a while and obviously not a best practice.

I was wondering if it's possible to store runtime variable values of your target process from a dynamic debugging session in your IDA database(or any other storage/tool) in some way. For example you run IDA debugger, or some external tool like olly/immunity, and store the encountered values (globals, function parameters) in IDA, so you can see actual values when doing your static analysis in IDA (for example on mouse over).

I don't know if anybody done this before, but it think it would be a really helpful feature.

**Is this possible, any similar tool/solution out there you know of? How do you process static+dynamic data of the reversed application?**

I'm not tied to IDA, but I find that environment to be most fitting for storing my result data. I'm interested in any solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> [**`funcap`**](https://github.com/deresz/funcap) uses IDA's debugging API to record function
>   calls in a program together with their arguments (before and after).
>
> This is very useful when dealing with malware which uses helper
>   functions to decrypt their strings, or programs which make many
>   indirect calls.

[image: a]

Comment: Just what I was looking for, what a great tool!